# mongoDB compass database makes every letter a new element

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

So I try to import a json file in a database

```
{"name":"Mark",
"age":"25"
}
```

When I try to import the file I get it back like

```
0:"M"
1:"a"
2:"r"
3:"k"
_id:objectId('etc')
```

and then inside a whole other element

```
_id:objectId('etc')
value:25
```

The id is supposed to be there because i am using uuid but is the data meant to be displayed this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think mongodb-compass expects an array of documents, so try to wrap it with `[]` if you import json file. If you import json-document no need for `[]`.

Like

```js
[
    {
        "name":"Mark",
         "age":"25"
    }
]
```